# How do I find the material that each face belongs to in PyWavefront?

Tags: python, pywavefront

I'm making a ray tracer in python 3, using PyWavefront to handle the .obj files. How can I get the material associations for each face? `Wavefront.mesh_list[0].faces` has the faces, but it's as a list of vertices without material data. `Wavefront.materials` contains the materials, but I can't find which face belongs to which material.